# Are there any other options to style an html page than css?

Tags: html, css

Css got pretty much features and has a fair amount of flexibility. Unlike other languages ive never heard of other options to expect the same result. Event js seams to be the only active laguage in html pages. Did i miss anything? Or are there acctually no other options?

Comment: whataver the technique you will use (js, SASS, etc) it will end with a CSS applied to your HTML

Comment: there are still no alternatives to HTML + CSS bond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not.

JSSS was an early competitor to CSS, but swiftly lost and nothing supports it today.

Technically, you could involve XSLT … but that would involve processes such as converting to XSL Formatting Objects and then to PDF rather than styling HTML per se.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are also CSS pre-processors like SASS, LESS and Stylus... that improves the syntax and complements CSS itself. That code from pre-processors is transpiled to CSS so any browser could execute it. But they aren't alternatives to CSS.

Comment: @Viira, I still think the correct term is 'transpiled' (not compiled).

Comment: Both has same meaning, if you're not satisfied you can revert it back to your original answer. No issues :)

Comment: Well, I'm thinking in compiling in terms of generating 'machine code'. Converting a language code to another language code with the same behaviour is to transpile.

Answer (score -1):

There are technologies like Jquery or other frameworks where you can just change the way you write CSS but there isn't a way in designing a page without CSS as all this uses it as a main framework for design.There are alternatives like Sass Scss but all this rely on css